# Definition of rare event in competing risk

Tags: survival, rare-events, competing-risks

I want to define rare event in competing risk. How many percent of the event must exist to be able to say that the event is rare? It can be said based on the EPV. But if the occurrence of the event is low, with what percentage can we say that the event is rare?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! "Rare" can mean a lot of things, depending on the context. Typically it's best to specify something like the fractions of events of different events, maybe over time, rather than define a competing events as "rare." Please edit the question to say more about why you need this type of definition of "rare" and how your statistical analysis might be affected if the competing event is considered "rare" or not.